# How do you prevent the back and forward broswer buttons from causing the page to reload and drop state when canceling navigation. React-router v4.3

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a page that takes in a number of user inputs and saves them using a react context object. The issue I am having is that if someone navigates away from the page before saving their entries, I want the user to be prompted to continue or cancel and keep the current page and state in tact. I initially had this set up with code like this in a useEffect hook that watched state change in the inputs.

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.onbeforeunload = () => {
        return true
    }
},[someState])
```

This worked for all types of browser navigation (refresh button, home button, closing window, entering a new url, etc..) but not when the back or forward buttons are clicked in the browser.

How do I get it so that clicking the back and forward buttons in the browser when the state is altered to not trigger a refresh on the page?

Answer (score 0):

This was a simple fix to my issue. If you look at the documentation for window.onbeforeunload, you'll see it mentions how chrome and firefox behave when this method is called. Specifically, two things need to be explicitly set depending on which browser is being used.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

By adding these two lines to the window.onbeforeunload in the useEffect hook, we get the desired behavior that the back and forward buttons do not trigger a refresh on the page.

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.onbeforeunload = () => {
        // For chrome
        e.returnValue = ''
    }
},[someState])
```